# Making the speed of SASS as fast as the CSS in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sass

Hi, let's look the code first.

I use the slim as the view template in Sinatra.

**Snippet 1** : template file, index.slim

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title = @title
        link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/origin.css'
        link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/sass.css'
    body
        div This is a test for SASS
```

**Snippet 2** : control file, route.rb that is a sinatra app file

```
require "sass"

configure do
    set :sass, :cache => true, :cache_location => './tmp/sass-cache', :style => :compressed
end

get '/' do
    @title = 'default page'
    slim :index
end

get '/css/sass.css' do
    sass :index
end
```

**Snippet 3** : 
style file

index.sass in my views folder that is a template path

```
div
    color: white
    background: green
```

origin.css in `/public/css/orgin.css` that is default style path

```
div {padding: 10px;margin: 10px;}
```

**Snippet 4 :** 
This is the log of server that shows the speed of orgin css file and sass file

```
[coolesting@localhost ds]$ rackup 
[2011-11-23 00:02:36] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-11-23 00:02:36] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [i686-linux]
[2011-11-23 00:02:36] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5285 port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 283 0.0261
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/origin.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0005
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/sass.css HTTP/1.1" 200 64 0.0060
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 283 0.0029
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/origin.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0005
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/sass.css HTTP/1.1" 200 64 0.0029
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 283 0.0190
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/origin.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0005
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/sass.css HTTP/1.1" 200 64 0.0043
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 283 0.0029
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/origin.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0005
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:38] "GET /css/sass.css HTTP/1.1" 200 64 0.0012
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 283 0.0056
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:39] "GET /css/sass.css HTTP/1.1" 200 64 0.0016
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:39] "GET /css/origin.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0187
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 283 0.0028
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:39] "GET /css/origin.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0005
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2011 00:02:39] "GET /css/sass.css HTTP/1.1" 200 64 0.0011
```

So, how to make the sass file running as fast as the origin css file, i have enabled the cache, but it slow than the origin css.

Or what solution to let the web server directly read the css file that is rendered from sass file.

Answer (score 0):

`:cache => true, :cache_location => '...'` is used to configure the internal SASS cache (which creates .sassc files to save time while compiling to css). So this cache doesn't prevent your Sinatra app to run SASS every time the browser requests /css/sass.css.

What you really want is that SASS renders the css (compiled from index.sass) to the file public/css/sass.css. Then it would be picked up by the static loading mechanism like the public/css/original.css file is. To accomplish this, have a look at

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options

specifically on the options `:template_location` and `:css_location`

Comment: I have ever set the `:css_location => './public/css'`(the :template_location is not set) option, but i can't see any CSS files is generated

Comment: I think that the way you use SASS within Sinatra is not supposed to generate files. For this, you should use the gem as described in http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#rackrailsmerb_plugin you should then not need to add an action to your application; The middleware should handle it for you (and it probably will create the files).

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually create the css files from scss and put them in your public directory. Otherwise the sass cache is already pretty fast.